# Merge [icc-profile] with [color-profile]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

From the definition of [color-profile](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color-profile):

> Color profile, or an ICC profile, is a set of data that characterizes a color input or output device, or a color space, according to standards promulgated by the International Color Consortium (ICC).

From that I suppose we don't need both tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done. And now I need 25 more characters for this answer.